# The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception and Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-8, 64-bit, asp.net-2.0

The same code runs in Windows 7 32 bit. But fails in windows 8 64 bit. Any  ideas? Thanks [image]

Comment: What code exactly failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just resolved it. This application requires 32-bit mode where as the IIS in my Windows 8 machine runs in 64-bit mode by default. I had to set Enable 32-bit Applications to true for the AppPool this application is using.

and it was not failing on a specific line of code. The exception was thrown somewhere between Application_BeginRequest and Session_Start